# prevent complete MySQL drop every time I update my Play framework website

Tags: java, mysql, frameworks, playframework, playframework-2.0

Every time I update my Play framework website, I get a message saying the database needs evolution.  Even when I only change a minor aspect of one table in the database, the whole database gets emptied.   How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: It's downvoated (and will be closed soon) cause you didn't wrote essential data: which version of Play you are using, which ORM etc...  Try to improve your question otherwise downvoters won't be able to change their minds...

Comment: I'm using Play 2.0.4.  Although this also occurred with 2.1-RC.  Again my question is general because this doesn't seem to be a bug having to do with version, it seems to be a configuration type of thing that I don't know how to change.  I'm using MySQL.  Any other questions?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your post is downvoted because of explanation lack.
However, I will try to help you.

Not sure this will help you, but I'm wondering it your issue comes from the persistence.xml file.

You may have something similar to

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
```

If you have it, replace it by (it won't drop your table again)

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
```

I hope I was not to far from your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I would leave a more detailed explanation but I just assumed most people knew what I was talking about because this is just how Play works by default... it's not like I'm claiming something is broken with my installation.  There is a support page about "Evolutions" and I tried changing that so it would stop dropping and re-creating my users table, but the file just gets overwritten.  In play's persistence.xml file, the only property is: <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Play 2 Java with default Ebean support take a look to the similar question asked in the same time: [How to handle Play Framework 2 database evolutions in production](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14616005/1066240) you'll find there an answer how to prevent dropping the DB.

In case of Ebean changing `persistance.xml` will not take any effect.

**Tip:** *It's important to write exactly which version of Play you are using, because... there are differences in default settings in `Play 1` vs. `Play 2 Java` vs `Play 2 Scala` etc. Also in each version you can use different techniques for DB accessing (`JDBC`, `Hibernate`, `Ebean` etc.) - you didn't specify that details, so it's hard to guess and therefore your question was downvoated.*