# Play + Ebean: Changes to the model + database

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm currently using `Java Play` and persisting models through `Ebean` to `MySQL`. This is going to be a generic question – what I see is that whenever I make changes to a model – sometimes just adding a property, after applying the evolution script, the existing data in the corresponding table gets truncated.

Since I love play and I'm thinking about deploying my next project using Play, this is an important question for me – is there a workaround to securely make model changes? Or is the behaviour I'm seeing only when running the application in development mode?

I can't find much about this subject elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's common approach of Ebean - it doesn't truncate your tables it just drops whole DB and recreates it with new DDL: [@see answer to the other question for explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14616490/1066240).

Note: In meantime I found that using standalone approach which is [MyBatis Migrations](http://mybatis.github.io/migrations/) is little bit more comfortable then Play's evolutions, anyway you need still to create the migrations manually (as evolutions).